# Spark Installation error, while building sbt package throwing some error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

While compiling "sbt package" inside spark, I got following error.

```
Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.12.4.jar
[info] Loading project definition from /home/hduser/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /home/hduser/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project
[info] Updating {git://github.com/ijuma/junit_xml_listener.git#fe434773255b451a38e8d889536ebc260f4225ce}default-6aef7c...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_1;0.12.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/hduser/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project/}plugins...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_1;0.12.4 ...
[info] downloading http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/0.9.2/jars/sbt-assembly.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.2!sbt-assembly.jar (4722ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.2.0/jars/sbteclipse-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.2.0!sbteclipse-plugin.jar (1619ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.2_0.12/1.5.1/sbt-idea-1.5.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1!sbt-idea.jar (3725ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/virtual-void/sbt-dependency-graph_2.9.2_0.12/0.7.3/sbt-dependency-graph-0.7.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.7.3!sbt-dependency-graph.jar (1932ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-core/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.2.0/jars/sbteclipse-core.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-core;2.2.0!sbteclipse-core.jar (4184ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mdr/ascii-graphs_2.9.2/0.0.2/ascii-graphs_2.9.2-0.0.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.mdr#ascii-graphs_2.9.2;0.0.2!ascii-graphs_2.9.2.jar (4871ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/hduser/.sbt/staging/90b1b0889ba1299e38f2/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
./sbt/sbt: line 50: 10232 Killed                  java -Xmx1200m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -jar ${JAR} "$@"
```

I am using,

Scala-2.10.3
Spark-0.9.0-incubating
Sbt-o.12.4

Is it require any additional settings. Great to assist me on the same.

Thanks,
Babu

Answer (score 1):

Set the minimum and maximum heap size before packaging by:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1300M -Xms1300M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"
```

see the following for more information:
[sbt manual installation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html)